# What is the code of whatsapp share for specific number?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, whatsapp

I'm programming on HTML CSS JS.
I wanna create a custom whatsapp massage area.
I have a problem, i want to send all the massages to one phone number.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you would need access to the WhatsApp API.
This [article](https://blog.cloudrail.com/whatsapp-api-how-to-use-the-whatsapp-chat-api/) is a good starting point.
In case you have a business you can have a look at the [WhatsApp Business App](https://blog.whatsapp.com/10000637/Introducing-the-WhatsApp-Business-App?l=en).
Can you provide more information?

Comment: Sure.
I'm trying to make a massage builder panel,
maybe like gmail text box or something like this...
I need to find a way to communicate person to person via phone, so I thought it was a nice way...